# When does a JSONObject become unordered?

Tags: java, json

I understand that a JSONObject contains key-value pairs that are not ordered. But, at what point does a JSONObject change its order? For instance, if I have a JSONObject such as

```
{"p1": 1, "p2": 2}
```

Will it become unordered if I don't modify it?

Comment: perhaps if HashMap is in use it will be unordered when maps back from Java to JSON

Comment: Read this answer: [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919039/691711).  You're kind of drifting into undefined behavior.  If something is not guarenteed to be ordered, I would say the script engine is permitted to change the ordering whenever it wants depending on the implementation.  What are you **actually** trying to accomplish?

Comment: @zero298 I am trying to read a JSONObject in two independent areas, and I was just wondering if those two reads would match up order-wise (say when printed). I do believe that I can use TreeMap or LinkedHashMap (as suggested below) to preserve order, but I was just curious if that is absolutely required if the JSONObject is unmodified, say if I'm just passing it in to another method or adding it to a List.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the order predicted by insertion use :

```
      JSONObject object = new JSONObject(new LinkedHashMap());
```